# Mother Earth in Latin - Personification

Tags: names, english-to-latin-translation

I'm looking for a Latin equivalent to the personification 'Mother Earth'. Does Matris Orbis or Mater Terram do the job? Do they translate in the same way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose *Mater Terra* or *Mater Tellus*.
See [online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) to see which word for "Earth" is more suitable.
If you mean the planet as a whole, I suggest *Tellus*.
If you mean the ground under our feet, I suggest *Terra*.
The most suitable nuance depends on context.

The Latin word for "Earth", whatever you choose, should be in nominative.
Here "Earth" behaves like a given name.
Thus *Orbis* would be grammatically fine but I doubt it means what you want.

**Edit:**
The Latin word order is quite free and I chose to put *Mater* first because it sounded best to me.
It seems that my intuition was wrong, as the examples in sumelic's answer demonstrate.
Therefore ***Terra Mater*** or ***Tellus Mater*** is better.
The word order I originally proposed is not wrong as far as I know, but it seems less idiomatic.

Comment: @sumelic, thank you making corpus searches to find a better word order! I had ignored the issue myself. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 10):

I see two approaches here: the literal and the historical one.

1. From a semantic point of view, your choice of words is mainly right, but as Joonas points, *[orbis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DO%3Aentry%20group%3D27%3Aentry%3Dorbis)* means primarily something round, and its assocaition (and meaning change into European languages) with the whole World derives from the fact that its use with *terrarum* and *terrae* (the roundness of the Earth, the round Earth) is rather common.

   Regarding the grammar, Latin noun endings change according to the function they fulfill in a sentece, hence:

   > **Mater Terra**,

   is the way to put it as a stand alone name, in an English text, or as the subject of a sentence, but bear in mind that this might change if you want to go further. For example, if it is the object of the action, in Latin you would rather say/write *Matrem Terram*, if you are talking about something else that *belongs* to Mother Earth you would go *Matris Terrae*, etc.
2. In case you want to stick to *Roman Mythology*, then Mother Earth as a godess actually has a proper noun:

   > **[Gaea](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0104%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DG%3Aentry%20group%3D1%3Aentry%3Dgaea-bio-1)** (equivalent to Greek [Gaia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_(mythology))).

Comment: Great job pointing out the goddess Gaea. That was my first thought as well, in the cultural context of ancient Rome.

Comment: Māter Terra, while not incorrect, immediately makes me think of the word mātertera "aunt"

Answer (score 9):

I agree with Joonas Ilmavirta's answer in that you want to use *tellus* or *terra* along with *mater.* But I am not sure which word order is more idiomatic in Latin. (It's true Latin word order is relatively "free," but there are still tendencies towards using certain orders in set phrases.)

A corpus search of "[Classical Latin Texts](http://latin.packhum.org/index)" (prepared bt The Packard Humanities Institute) turned up the following sentence from *[Carmen Devotionis](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/306/1/0/1100-1106#0)*:

> **Tellus mater** teque Iuppiter obtestor.

I believe this is an example of the phrase "tellus mater" being used as a single noun phrase meaning "mother earth"; however I am not a fluent reader of Latin so my analysis of the grammar of this sentence may be incorrect.

Some other relevant results I found using this corpus:

> primum, qui omnis fructos agri culturae caelo et terra continent,
>   Iovem et Tellurem: itaque, quod ii parentes, magni dicuntur, Iuppiter
>   pater appellatur, Tellus terra mater. ([Rerum Rusticarum de Agri Cultura, Liber Primus](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/684/2/3/1567-1578#3), 
>   Marcus Terentius Varro)

- seems to use "terra mater" as a title for Tellus.

> Terra mater est in medio quasi ovum   15.1 corrotundata, et omnia bona
>   in se habet tamquam favus'. ([Petronius, *Satyrica* 39.1.1](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/972/1/22/2037-2048#22))

- seems to use "terra mater" as a poetic term for the Earth.

I was not able to find any results when I searched for "mater terra" or "mater tellus" in this corpus.

Comment: Good findings! I wondered which word order to take, but I ended up not discussing it since I had nothing to say about it. I will add a note to my answer.

Comment: The name Iuppiter itself is also relevant: It's Iu-piter, not *Pater Iu. (Likewise the rarer Marspiter.)