# A Royal Title for a Fictional King

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, grammar-choice

So, I'm trying to make a royal title in Latin for a fictional king. I tried to model it heavily after Queen Elizabeth II's royal title to keep myself as accurate as possible and I came up with:

English:

> Demetrius the First, By the Grace of Earth, of the Kingdom of Raetia and the territories across the world/sea that are under Raetian law, King, Messenger of the Faith

Latin:

> Demetrius I, Terrae Gratia Raetiae Regni et terrarum transmarinarum quae in ditione sunt Raetica Rex, Fidei Nuntius

And I just want to know what might be wrong with it. Some backstory: On a colonized planet (by an Earth Federation) is a religion that believes Earth is actually heaven and by saying 'By the Grace of Earth' is like the mandate of heaven in Chinese dynastic tradition.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice question! If you want to give it a more Roman/Classical flavor, you could say by the grace of [Gaea](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/mother-earth-in-latin-personification/1817#1817)

Comment: Or Tellus. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_(mythology)

Comment: Thanks! These people do not live on Earth and much of their knowledge of Latin is purely from Earth literature. It's like Space Middle Ages for these people, except they have somewhat modern technology. So I would assume their knowledge of Gaea or Tellus may be limited.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider borrowing the French and Spanish royal titles "Rex Christianissimus" and "Rex Catholicissimus" respectively.

Answer (score 0):

- Why the choice of  [ditio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=ditio) a "less correct form for dicio"?
- As "quae ... sunt Raetica" means "territories that ... are Raetian", then Raetica should be nominative feminine plural, "Raeticae."

Comment: *Raetica* agrees with *ditione*, so that is correct.

Comment: But then wouldn't this mean "by Raetian law"?

Comment: *In ditione* = “under the rule.” In the [original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_of_the_British_sovereign#British_sovereigns): *terrarum transmarinarum quae in ditione sunt Britannica Rex* = “king of the overseas territories that are under British rule.”

Comment: I see, so it would mean "Raetian rule" parallel to "British rule." The question asks for "by law, are Raetian". So I see arguments for each. And thank you for showing where the choice of the word "ditio" comes from.

Comment: I made a mistake in the English translation, haha.